# How can i deploy or create lists on site/subsite i want?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part

I have a SharePoint-hosted App-part (ClientWePart), and my app-part are dependent on a couple of lists to be created.

At the moment all my lists are created on the hostWeb `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`. I want my lists to be created on the site app-part are deployed on. I am using `REST` to create my lists when app is installed/deployed...

All my lists are created on:

```
http://app-7e2216cc1cce65.gonadnapps.com/sites/devsite
```

and my app URL is :

```
http://app-7e2216cc1cce65.gonadnapps.com/sites/devsite/manage/SimpliManageProsessModulH16
```

And my App-Part is deployed on URL:

```
http://app-7e2216cc1cce65.gonadnapps.com/sites/devsite/manage
```

And I want my lists to be created on the site URL above, "manage"...

I was also trying to find out to get Site Title of where my app-part are deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

`var spHostUrl = makeAbsUrl(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.substring(0, _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.lastIndexOf("/")));`

The reason for doing this is, I want my lists to be created on subsite name "manage", and not on the root site (`siteAbsoluteUrl`). And later I want all my REST call to point to the lists created under subsite "Manage".

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing [standard tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163816.aspx) when your app is opened, the `SPHostUrl` query string value will point back to the website where the app is hosted.

You can retrieve that value (and setup the `AppContextSite` if you're using the JSOM) with something like:

```
var qsVals = SP.ScriptHelpers.getDocumentQueryPairs(); //use the ScriptHelpers library
var hostWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(qsVals.SPHostUrl);
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebUrl);
```

If you're using the [cross domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn790708.aspx) you'll have the host web URL value in `hostWebUrl`

If you need to go one level up or down you can use some string manipulation to navigate the URL hierarchy.